# TensorFlow: How to combine my retrained categories with tensorflow's imagenet categories

Tags: tensorflow

After I retrain for new categories according to : https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining#training_on_your_own_categories

use command like:

```
bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image && \
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image \
--graph=/tmp/output_graph.pb --labels=/tmp/output_labels.txt \
--output_layer=final_result \
--image=$HOME/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg
```

It only could recognize the image from my retrained categories. How to recognize the image both from my retrained categorieds & tensorflow's imagenet categories?

Thanks!